# Keep "best" checkpoints instead of latest ones

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

When using [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), you can only set how many recent checkpoint files you'de like to keep using [`keep_checkpoint_max`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/RunConfig#keep_checkpoint_max)

Is there a way to keep the "best" checkpoint files instead of the recent ones?

"best" has to be defined based on the training/eval metrics.

Example: if "best" is defined as "*the lowest loss on validation set*", then one should keep this value for each checkpoint saved so far to be able to compare when a new checkpoint arrives.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't think that is possible directly in tensorflow at the momemt: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8658. But a non efficient way would be to keep a track of the maximum validation score and save the model whenever you get a better score. Also, keras does have support to save the best model if you can use keras in your use case.

Comment: How about [BestExporter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BestExporter)?